# Change state with dropdown reactstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

I am creating a Dropdown using reactstrap and I want to change the value of `dropDownValueNav` as I select a different item of the Dropdown.

The problem is inside my `onClick` function. There I set the state of my new value but it does not change immediately; it only does so on the second click.

How can I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import {
  Row,
  Card,
  Nav,
  Navbar,
  NavItem,
  UncontrolledDropdown,
  DropdownToggle,
  DropdownItem,
  DropdownMenu,
} from 'reactstrap';
import { withTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import DownIcon from 'mdi-react/ChevronDownIcon';
import {
  Link,
  NavLink,
} from 'react-router-dom';


class Menu extends PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    t: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dropDownValueNav: 'Home,
      dropdownOpen: false,
    };
  }

  toggle = () => {
    const { dropdownOpen } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      dropdownOpen: !dropdownOpen,
    });
    console.log(this.state.dropdownOpen)
  };

  changeValueSecondary = (e) => {
    this.setState({ dropDownValueNav: e.currentTarget.textContent });
    console.log(e.currentTarget.textContent);
    console.log('state', this.state.dropDownValueNav);
  };

  render() {
    const { t } = this.props;
    const { dropdownOpen, dropDownValueNav } = this.state;

    return (
      <Card inverse>

        <Row>
          <div className="col-auto">

            <Navbar>
              <Nav className="text_lg" navbar>
                <UncontrolledDropdown toggle={this.toggle} isOpen={dropdownOpen}>
                  <DropdownToggle nav>
                    {dropDownValueNav}
                  </DropdownToggle>

                  <DropdownMenu>
                    <DropdownItem onClick={this.changeValueSecondary}>
                      <Link to="/react">react</Link>
                    </DropdownItem>

                    <DropdownItem onClick={this.changeValueSecondary}>
                      <Link to="/html">html</Link>
                    </DropdownItem>

                    <DropdownItem onClick={this.changeValueSecondary}>
                      <Link to="/css">css</Link>
                    </DropdownItem>
                  </DropdownMenu>
                </UncontrolledDropdown>
              </Nav>
            </Navbar>

        </Row>

      </Card>
    );
  }
}

export default withTranslation('common')(Menu);
```

Comment: Since setState is async, your console.log will still display the previous state. To access the new state, use the seconds setState parameter callback.

Comment: @Domino987 would you show me an example plis?

Comment: its in the docs: this.setState((state, props) => {
  return {counter: state.counter + props.step};
}, () => console.log(this.state)// this is the new state);

Answer (score 0):

setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater, callback)).

Do like this to see in console updated state:

```
toggle = () => {
    const { dropdownOpen } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      dropdownOpen: !dropdownOpen,
    }, () => console.log(this.state.dropdownOpen))
};

changeValueSecondary = (e) => {
    this.setState(
       { dropDownValueNav: e.currentTarget.textContent },
       () => console.log('state', this.state.dropDownValueNav)
    );
    console.log(e.currentTarget.textContent);

};
```

Answer (score 0):

The setState() works asynchronously, so it batches the updates to states together for performance purposes.[More Details](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html)

To overcome this race condition, there are few ways you can write this.

1. You can use a callback function in which you can call the console.log() which will show you the updated option.
2. You can try and user prevState as parameter to the setState() and can use that to update the states.
3. You can also write updater functions which you can call in callbacks to update states.

Examples for all the option.

```
toggle = () => {
    this.setState({
      this.state.dropdownOpen: !this.state.dropdownOpen}, 
        () => console.log(this.state.dropdownOpen)
    )
};

changeValueSecondary = (e) => {
    this.setState({ 
        this.state.dropDownValueNav: e.currentTarget.textContent},
            () => console.log(this.state.dropDownValueNav)
    );
};
```

OR

```
toggle = () => {
this.setState((prevState) => ({
    dropdownOpen: !prevState.dropdownOpen
    }));
};

changeValueSecondary = (e) => {
    this.setState({ 
        this.state.dropDownValueNav: e.currentTarget.textContent},
            () => doSomeThingWithTheUpdatedState();
    );
};

doSomeThingWithTheUpdatedState = () => {
    //Use the new value of the state.dropDownValueNav
}
```

Also for advanced applications, you can use the reducers to be called which will eventually update the states before you can use them.